# Custom RepositoryRestController Mapping url throws 404 in spring-data-rest

Tags: controller, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have written a custom `RepositoryRestController` using its corresponding entity repository. When performing request on this url, the query is running in my console, but the url returns 404. I also able to see the requestHandlerMapping for this url in logs. Refer my following code snippet.

**Repository:**

```
   @RepositoryRestResource
    public interface FooRepository extends BaseRepository<Foo, Integer> {
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    List<Foo> findByName(String name);
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class FooResource {
@Aurowired
FooRepository fooRepository;

@Autowired
RestApiService restApiService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/foos/search/byApiName", method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> findByApiName(String name) {
List<String> apiNames = restApiService.getNameLike(name);
List<Foo> fooList = fooRepository.findByName(name);

List<String> fooNames = // list of names from fooList
...
System.out.println("FETCHING apiNames");
return apiNames;
}
```

When I execute the following curl command

```
curl -X GET http:localhost:8080/foos/search/byApiName
```

the response returns 404 error. I don't know why. But he printout statement is printing in console.

@hat I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Tipically 404 error in Spring means that you are missing the context root. And you are calling the service without it. Try add it after port number and before `/foos`. Usually is the name of the project. E.g `http://localhost:8080/SpringWeb/foos/search/byApiName`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest that you need to add the `@ResponseBody` to either your method or to the return value (as in the SDR example http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers) or wrap your list in an ResponseEntity.

Not sure if there are any differences between these approaches but all should, as noted in the Spring MVC docs:

> "indicate that the return type should be written straight to the HTTP
>   response body (and not placed in a Model, **or [be] interpreted as a view
>   name)**."

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody

Given you debug statement prints but you get a 404 it would seem the latter action is what happens.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foos/search/byApiName", method = GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> findByApiName(String name) {
    // ....
}
```

or,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foos/search/byApiName", method = GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> findByApiName(String name) {
   //....
}
```

or,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foos/search/byApiName", method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> findByApiName(String name) {
   //....

  return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(fooNames, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found out that the controller need the annotation `@RequestMapping`, otherwise it will be ignored. Below is my code:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/security")
public class ...
```

This works for me.

Comment: This should not be done. As it will register the controller twice.
Spring data rest even has an error for this now.