# application.properties not used when developing custom controller with MongoRepository in spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I'm writing a simple spring boot backend application which uses MongoDB. I'm using spring data rest for the classic rest api calls and then developing a couple of custom controllers. I started develop it with a local mongo db instance and everything worked fine. Now I'm moving to a proper mongo db instance in another server and I've some problem using the custom controllers. I set `spring.data.mongodb.host` and  `spring.data.mongodb.port` on my application.properties and the rest apis provided by spring data rest work successfully: I can insert and get data with no problem. But when I try to call the custom controller it looks like is still trying to connect to a local instance as I get this error message from the log:

`com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]`

This is my repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "deployment", path = "deployment")
public interface DeploymentRepository extends MongoRepository<DeploymentRecord, String> {

    public List<DeploymentRecord> findByVmNameOrderByDeploymentTimeDesc(@Param("vmName") String vmName);

    public DeploymentRecord findFirstByVmNameOrderByDeploymentTimeDesc(@Param("vmName") String vmName);

}
```

and this is the start of the custom controller:

```
@RestController
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = {HypermediaType.HAL})
public class EnvironmentController {

    @Autowired
    private DeploymentRepository deploymentRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listEnvironmentResources", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
    public Resources<Resource<EnvironmentRecordResource>> getEnvironmentResourceList(){
```

This is the application (the default, basically)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The object data it's very simple, string fields and just getters.

How can I configure the custom controller to use the same configuration used by the self generated rest api that are on the application.properties?

Thanks,
Michele.

**UPDATE**

I tried to override the configuration creating my own

```
@Configuration
public class SpringMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration{ 

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception 
    {
        return new MongoClient(env.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.host") , Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("spring.data.mongodb.port")) );
    }

    public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception 
    {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), getDatabaseName());
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "test";
    }    
}
```

Still, this is read only by the standard api, custom controller wants to connect to 127.0.0.1:

```
 2017-11-23 11:44:02.441  INFO 7 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
 2017-11-23 11:44:02.452  INFO 7 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017

 com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar!/:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Comment: try with this 
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class})`

Comment: Not a 100% sure, but try replacing the Restcontroller annotation with [RepositoryRestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers). Another thing, try to use `spring.data.mongodb.uri` in application.properties instead of setting host and port separately. It shouldn't act different, but it's worth the try.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried `spring.data.mongodb.uri` and as expected it does not change. I tried to use the RepositoryRestController but in that case my custom controller is not working at all (it returns a 404). The self generated apis still work correctly.

Comment: The MongoAutoConfiguration exclude prevents the application from start at all with this error: `Parameter 0 of method mongoDbFactory in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.mongodb.MongoClient' that could not be found.
        - Bean method 'mongo' not loaded because auto-configuration 'MongoAutoConfiguration' was excluded`

Comment: The weird thing with the RepositoryRestController is that reading the log the url seems to be provisioned correctly but still receive a 404 :-/

Comment: Fixed the 404 problem using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480509/custom-repositoryrestcontroller-mapping-url-throws-404-in-spring-data-rest . The behavior does not change. Custom controller always pointing to 127.0.0.1